# how can i detect if an iframe video not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've seen some website have a video in multiple video streaming websites like Fembed or vidcast and some of the time the links are broken for whatever reason but I've seen a website that actually detects if the video source is broken and changed to a new one I wonder how can I detect broken link in Iframe?

Comment: You can try a get request on the url to see if a 404 page is returned. You'll need a cors bypass. Also you cannot access the DOM of an iframe that does not belong to your domain.

Comment: As @John noted if the CORS is blocked you have no way to check from the browser, you can write a simple server function that will test for your clients.

Comment: You can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a free alternative